# Javascript runtime Object doesn't support this property error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function which get's me the `emailID` of the respective text added.

But what happens if the `EmailID` doesn't exist's it gives me error as

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is the function.

```
function getEmailIdByType() {
        StrPriFnName = "FunGetEmailIdByType(" + document.getElementById('TxtPartyName').value + ")";
        var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET", "FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para=" + StrPriFnName, false);
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");

        if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != "") {
            var StrPriData = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.Split('~');
            document.getElementById('TxtEmail').value = StrPriData[1];
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It gives me error at line:-

```
var StrPriData = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.Split('~');
```

Comment: I think Split should be lower case i.e. split() not Split()

Comment: @Sami: tried with lower case, but it fills the `EmailID` box as `undefined`. **I want if the Email-ID does not exist, the textbox should remain blank..**

Comment: Lower case split, use XmlHTTPRequest and lower case your variable name's first letter.

Comment: @N K,  handle undefined with code like this .. var x = y !== undefined ? y : 1;  Also mentioned in my answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != "") {
            var StrPriData = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.Split('~');
            document.getElementById('TxtEmail').value = typeof StrPriData[1] != "undefined" ? StrPriData[1] : "";
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to access the `responseText` only when the  `ObjPriXMLHTTP` changes it's `readyState`

```
 ObjPriXMLHTTP.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (ObjPriXMLHTTP.readyState == 4 && ObjPriXMLHTTP.status == 200) {

     var StrPriData = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.split('~');

 }
```

Probably the `responseText` property is only available after it got a response. The response hasn't really arrived where you try to see it.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) is a full example.

Comment: thanks for the answer Charlie, the other one is working perfectly fine. Still I will keep the logic for future reference

Comment: Does it give you the email ID?

Comment: The other answer cannot help you getting the EmailID. It just prevents error from occurring when the property is not there. It didn't bring the property back.